# Enrich ASP.Net bearer token format

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, bearer-token

I have setup an ASP.NET WebApi project with support of bearer token like this:

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

var oAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(oAuthBearerOptions);
```

When I make a request to the token endpoint I have this answer

```
{
    "access_token":"GST9UwSuesiYhkezr94K4xwuzvNQ",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":86399
}
```

Is there any way to enrich the token with additional fields like this?

```
{
    "access_token":"GST9UwSuesiYhkezr94K4xwuzvNQ",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":86399,
    "username":"user@mail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is the solution:

In your class that inherits from **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider**

```
public override async Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("username", "user@mail.com");

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly would you put that? In which class?